# Python- list of prime number in range one line code

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension, primes

How to write in one line method that checks if the number is prime or not in range of numbers?
The return value is a list of prime/not each number in the range.

Output example:
`[“prime”, “not prime”...”not prime”' ,“prime`]

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: What is the point of the one-line constraint? What range are we talking about? 1-(2**12345678-1) will obviously be slightly more complex than 1-12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
# one line
primes = ["prime" if num > 1 and len([i for i in range(2, int(num / 2+1)) if num % i == 0]) == 0 else "not prime" for num in num_list]

# e.g.
>>> num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
>>> primes = ["prime" if num > 1 and len([i for i in range(2, int(num / 2+1)) if num % i == 0]) == 0 else "not prime" for num in num_list]
>>> primes
['not prime', 'prime', 'prime', 'not prime', 'prime', 'not prime', 'prime', 'not prime', 'not prime', 'not prime', 'prime']
```

The inner list comprehension (i.e. `[i for i in range(2, int(num / 2+1)) if num % i == 0]`) is used to check whether the number has other factors apart from `1` and itself.